# Switching from Node installed with brew to Node installed with n

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I have problem with switching from one version of node to another. When I run `node -v` i got: `v10.24.0`. And this version was installed with brew. Now I have to run something with older version of node (10.16.3), so I installed `n` package (`npm install -g n` ) and switched to desired version: `sudo n 10.16.3`. And I got:

```
installed : v10.16.3 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v10.24.0 at /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
```

Version .24 is installed with brew and .16 with n library. I was trying to remove version installed with brew (`brew unlink node, brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node`), but still while checking versions I got v10.24.0. Could somebody tell me what else should I do to use the older version?

Comment: I think you want to use `node@10` with brew. You could also install `nvm` instead because uninstalling node is going to effect `npm` and anything installed from it

Comment: I also highly recommend using nvm or some Docker image, it's simpler to handle any Node project -- nvm worked great to me, even better than using any OS-related package manager to install Node; but Docker helps a lot to develop in many languages and also configuring things like DBs and reverse proxy without the need to install anything besides Docker.